# how to eliminate the header in the responce of utl_http.read_text in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Need help in eliminating the headers from the  UTL_HTTP.read_text.sorry to pitch in to my doubts directly.

I have a code where im trying to connect a WSDL from the pl/sql program
In my code i was using  UTL_HTTP.read_text instead of UTL_HTTP.READ_LINE.

```
UTL_HTTP.read_text(l_http_resp,l_text,32767);
DBMS_LOB.writeappend (l_ws_response, LENGTH(l_text), l_text);
```

Read_line:

```
utl_http.read_line(l_http_resp, l_ws_response);
```

The reason for me to choose read_text instead of read_line is, the request which was fed to the UTL_http has more data than the varchar2 limit and it was working when I use read_text instead of read_line(as suggested by ASK TOM).

Now when I use read_text the header is getting appended with the response.

Sample output, when I use read_text

*** Print header from the response

```
Connection: close
Date: Tue, 15 May 2018 08:55:12 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

** Print details from response - 08:55:14.319

```
 Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">...
```

Before the xml begins, the text **"Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1"** is getting along with xml response, but, when i use read_line im getting only the read_line, how to eliminate the header from the response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to read longer strings from web service I use this code:

```
   l_http_request    UTL_HTTP.REQ;
   l_http_response   UTL_HTTP.RESP;
   BUFFER   VARCHAR2(32767);
   l_response_clob   CLOB;
    xml XMLTYPE;

BEGIN

    ...
    l_http_response := UTL_HTTP.GET_RESPONSE(l_http_request);

    DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY(l_response_clob, TRUE, DBMS_LOB.CALL);
    DBMS_LOB.OPEN(l_response_clob, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);

    BEGIN
    LOOP
        UTL_HTTP.READ_TEXT(l_http_response, BUFFER, 32767);
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND(l_response_clob, LENGTH(BUFFER), BUFFER);
    END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN UTL_HTTP.END_OF_BODY THEN
            UTL_HTTP.END_RESPONSE(l_http_response);
    END;
    DBMS_LOB.CLOSE(l_response_clob);

    xml := XMLTYPE(l_response_clob);
    ... do whatever you need with XML docuemnt

    DBMS_LOB.FREETEMPORARY(l_response_clob);

END;
```

Comment: i used the same, it works for the longer string, but still , it gets appended with the header

Comment: Try `REGEXP_REPLACE(l_response_clob, '^.*<\?xml', '<?xml')`

Comment: thanks it worked, Thought of this as a secondary solution, But any idea on why the header being carried along with the response?